# File Access Strategy in a Multi-Threaded Environment (Web App)

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, web-applications, caching, file-io

I have a file which is an XML representation of some data that is taken from a Web service and cached locally within a Web Application. The idea being is that this data is *very* static, but just *might* change. So I have set it up to cache to a file, and stuck a monitor against it to check if it has been deleted. Once deleted, the file will be refreshed from its source and rebuilt.

I am now running in to problems though, because obviously in a multi-threaded environment it falls over as it is trying to access the data when it is still reading/writing the file.

This is confusing me, because I added a object to lock against, and this is always locked during read/write. It was my understanding that attempted access from other threads would be told to "wait" until the lock was released?

Just to let you know, I am real new to multi-threaded development, so I am totally willing to accept this is a screw up on my part :)

- **Am I missing something?**
- **What is the best file access strategy in a multi-threaded environment?**

  ---

#### Edit

Sorry - I should have said this is using **ASP.NET 2.0** :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code that I use to make sure a file is not locked by another process.  It's not 100% foolproof, but it gets the job done most of the time:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks until the file is not locked any more.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fullPath"></param>
    bool WaitForFile(string fullPath)
    {
        int numTries = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            ++numTries;
            try
            {
                // Attempt to open the file exclusively.
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                    FileShare.None, 100))
                {
                    fs.ReadByte();

                    // If we got this far the file is ready
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogWarning(
                   "WaitForFile {0} failed to get an exclusive lock: {1}", 
                    fullPath, ex.ToString());

                if (numTries > 10)
                {
                    Log.LogWarning(
                        "WaitForFile {0} giving up after 10 tries", 
                        fullPath);
                    return false;
                }

                // Wait for the lock to be released
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        Log.LogTrace("WaitForFile {0} returning true after {1} tries",
            fullPath, numTries);
        return true;
    }
```

Obviously you can tweak the timeouts and retries to suit your application.  I use this to process huge FTP files that take a while to be written.

Answer (score 1):

If you're locking on a object stored as a *static* then the lock should work for all threads in the same Application Domain, but perhaps you need to upload a code sample so we can have a look at the offending lines.

That said, one thought would be to check if IIS is configured to run in [Web Garden](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/57fd3d02-9b05-4b3f-8c3a-f326ff895ab8.mspx?mfr=true) mode (i.e. more than 1 process executing your application) which would break your locking logic. While you could fix such a situation with a mutex it'd be easier to reconfigure your application to execute in a single process, although you'd be wise to check the performance before and after messing with the web garden settings as it can potentially affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe create the file with a temporary name ("data.xml_TMP"), and when it's ready change the name to what it is supposed to be. That way, no other process will be accessing it before it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have been working on this and ended up creating a stress-test module to basically hammer the crap out of my code from several threads ([See Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568/whats-the-best-way-to-unit-test-from-multiple-threads)).

It was much easier from this point on to find holes in my code. It turns out that my code wasn't actually far off, but there was a certain logic path that it could enter in to which basically caused read/write operations to stack up, meaning if they didn't get cleared in time, it would go boom!

Once I took that out, ran my stress test again, all worked fine!

**So, I didn't really do anything *special* in my file access code, just ensured I used [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.85).aspx) statements where appropriate (i.e. when reading or writing).**

Answer (score 0):

How about using `AutoResetEvent` to communicate between threads? I created a console app which creates roughly 8 GB file in `createfile` method and then copy that file in `main` method

```
 static AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static string filePath=@"C:\Temp\test.txt";
    static string fileCopyPath=@"C:\Temp\test-copy.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in main method");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Thread thread = new Thread(createFile);
        thread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("waiting for file to be processed ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine();

        File.Copy(filePath, fileCopyPath);
        Console.WriteLine("file copied ");

    }


    static void createFile()
    {

        FileStream fs= File.Create(filePath);            
        Console.WriteLine("start processing a file "+DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < 300000000; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("The value of i is " + i);

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("file processed " + DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine();

        waitHandle.Set();
    }
```