# Read log file being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, remote-desktop

**Goal**

I want to press a button on my GUI and read in the seclog.log file (symantec AV log) from a remote machine and display the contents of the log to a rich text box in my application.

**Things That Work**

everything but reading the log file

**Error Message**

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
Message=The process cannot access the file '\\HOSTNAME\C$\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\seclog.log' because it is being used by another process.
Source=mscorlib
```

**code**

```
//possible seclog paths
        String seclogPath1 = @"\\\\" + target + "\\C$\\Program Files (x86)\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\seclog.log";
        String seclogPath2 = @"\\\\" + target + "\\C$\\Program Files\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\seclog.log";

        //if seclog exists
        if (File.Exists(seclogPath1))
        {
            //output.AppendText("file exists at " + seclogPath1);
            //var seclogContent = File.Open(seclogPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(seclogPath1);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            output.AppendText(str);
            streamReader.Close();
            stream.Close();


        }
```

**Things I've Tried**

[File is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737444/file-is-being-used-by-another-process)

[C# The process cannot access the file ''' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803929/c-sharp-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth)

Googling the issue

using filestreams in multiple ways

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
//possible seclog paths
String seclogPath1 = @"\\\\" + target + "\\C$\\Program Files (x86)\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\seclog.log";
String seclogPath2 = @"\\\\" + target + "\\C$\\Program Files\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\seclog.log";

//if seclog exists
if (File.Exists(seclogPath1))
{
    //output.AppendText("file exists at " + seclogPath1);
    //var seclogContent = File.Open(seclogPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

    Stream stream = File.Open(seclogPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    //File.OpenRead(seclogPath1);
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    output.AppendText(str);
    streamReader.Close();
    stream.Close();


}
```

**what i had to change**

i had to create a readwrite filestream

**original code**

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(seclogPath1);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

**new code**

```
Stream stream = File.Open(seclogPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
//File.OpenRead(seclogPath1);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: Nice, you found the solution. I was going to give you a link to a post with the same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560651/whats-the-least-invasive-way-to-read-a-locked-file-in-c-sharp-perhaps-in-unsaf

Comment: @joshgo thanks! i was staring at the code for like and hour before i figured that out. lol

Comment: This solution worked for me with an implementation of Serilog. Similar situation, we needed to read a section of the log file to present in a web front end, but the read failed, this resolved it.

Comment: if doesn't exists the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, true))
{
   sr.Close(); //This is mandatory
   //Do your file operation
}
```

Comment: The using should close it for you?

Comment: I tried but it's not closing. So I have to explicitly call .close.

Comment: Problem should be somewhere else https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx