# How to send a database that is being used by another process to email c#

Tags: c#, process

In my program I am sending a database in the `form_closed` event to my email , in in `form_load`event I want to get the database from my email and to use it .
I'm doing this to get the database from another computers in my project.

but the problem is in this line :

```
Attachment database = new Attachment("DataBase\\USBrowser.accdb");
```

I get an exception that the database is being used by another process , how to deal with this problem ?
can I stop the database of being used by another process? ,, any other suggestions are welcomed .

thanx in advance

Comment: Are you by any chance reading the file at form_load and not disposing of the object?

Comment: After the project is closed and disposed, when I enter it again I want to get the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is:

> How to read a file being used by another process?

Then you can access it in "read mode":

```
Stream stream = File.Open("DataBase\\USBrowser.accdb", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942717/read-log-file-being-used-by-another-process)

Answer (score 1):

If your program is using the database then you will need to stop the database before using it.

You might also be able to make a copy of the database before attempting to add it as an attachment and then add the copy.

Comment: can I make a copy of a file that is used by another process ?

Comment: It depends on how the "other" process is reading it. Ill update my answer to include some code in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to find out if another program has it open (Excel or something)

Process Explorer can help with this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx