# Generate One XML(LogData.xml) file from Two different Application Without Threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to write XML Log File from two or more Application into LogData.xml file. while running the one application it creats the LogData.xml file correctly but at the same time both the allpication are run simulteniously and try to write the LogData.xml file it gives me an error message such as **The process cannot access the file Log_Data.xml' because it is being used by another process.** 
I use this code

```
public void WriteXmlLog(string logType, string logFlag, string logModule, string logLocation, string logText, string logStackTrace)
        {
 if (!File.Exists(_logFilePath))
            {
                //File.WriteAllText(_logFilePath, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>\r\n<AppXmlLogWritter></AppXmlLogWritter>");
                XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(_logFilePath, null);
                textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
                textWritter.WriteStartElement("AppXmlLogWritter");
                textWritter.WriteEndElement();
                textWritter.Close();
            }
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_logFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {

                string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                xmlDoc.Load(fileStream);
                XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogData");
                XmlElement xmlLogID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogID");
                XmlElement xmlLogDateTime = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogDateTime");
                XmlElement xmlLogType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogType");
                XmlElement xmlLogFlag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogFlag");
                XmlElement xmlLogApplication = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogApplication");
                XmlElement xmlLogModule = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogModule");
                XmlElement xmlLogLocation = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogLocation");
                XmlElement xmlLogText = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogText");
                XmlElement xmlLogStackTrace = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogStackTrace");

                xmlLogID.InnerText = _logIDPrefix + currentDateTime + randomNumber;
                xmlLogDateTime.InnerText = currentDateTime;
                xmlLogType.InnerText = ((LogTypes)Convert.ToInt32(logType)).ToString();
                xmlLogFlag.InnerText = logFlag;
                xmlLogApplication.InnerText = _logApplication;
                xmlLogModule.InnerText = logModule;
                xmlLogLocation.InnerText = logLocation;
                xmlLogText.InnerText = logText;
                xmlLogStackTrace.InnerText = logStackTrace;

                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogID);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogDateTime);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogType);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogFlag);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogApplication);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogModule);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogLocation);
                newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogText);

                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);

                //}
                //finally
                //{
                //    objMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                //}

            }
            xmlDoc.Save(_logFilePath);
        }
```

**I want to achive this without Threading**

Comment: I think your only option would probably be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744/wait-until-file-is-unlocked-in-net

Comment: @srk : You cannot do something like that. One application needs to wait until the other has finished writing. check this link to implement it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316700/locking-xml-file-in-web-application?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try implementing logging with [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) in both applications and set as the target the same xml.