# How to use FileSystemWatcher to check whether a file is locked by another process?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wait until file is unlocked in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744/wait-until-file-is-unlocked-in-net)

I have many cases where a program must wait until a file is unlocked by another process (e.g file being copied) before it can be used again. A standard solution is to wait for it iterating in a loop using Thread.Sleep(). I don't consider that kind nice. I've read it's possible to do it with the FileSystemWatcher of .NET (I'm using C#). Can anyone illustrate it? Thanks a lot for your replies!

Comment: no.  FileSystemWatcher does not tell you when a file handle is released.

Comment: But it fires a sertain event if a file is created. Couldn't that be a solution for my issue?

Comment: A file being unlocked is not the same as one being created.

Comment: In the general case, even if you can find a way to be notified that a file has become unlocked, by the time your code is running and making an attempt to acquire the file, it's possible that some other process has taken a new lock. You *have* to write code that reacts to the file being locked when you attempt to acquire it *anyway*.

Comment: If another process takes a new lock while the program running, it's possible to avoid the interference with deregistration of the event: `code`watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;`code`

Answer (score 2):

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) as the name suggests ,lets you **watch** for any events that occur when you `change`,`create`,`delete`,`rename` a file or folder

You cannot use `FileSystemWatcher` to check if the file is locked..

Answer (score 0):

```
FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
int _watcherEventFiredCounter;

_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher {
    Path = @"C:\temp",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
    Filter = "*.zip",
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

_watcher.Changed += OnChanged;


private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    _watcherEventFiredCounter++;
    // The event is fired two times: on start copying and on finish copying
    if (_watcherEventFiredCounter == 2) {
        Console.WriteLine("Copying is finished now!");
        _watcherEventCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Now the question is how can come back to the calling thread?

Comment: You can may take a look at the answer I gave to the Original Question of which yours is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42782410/6754146