# Download File and Extract Immediately - File is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.5, webclient

I'm looping through a list of zip files and downloading them from a WebClient.  I'm trying to extract them immediately after they download, but getting an error that the file is being used by another process.

> Error: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\test.zip' because it is being used by another process.

The only thing that I can think of is that maybe the file is still "in use" for a short time after being downloaded?  DownloadFile does block ("This method blocks while downloading the resource." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx), so I can't see it being an issue with the file still downloading.

Any ideas on a workaround?

```
Using client As New WebClient
    oLog.Info("Downloading " & strFileServer & " to " & strFileLocal & "...")
    If Not Directory.Exists(strPathLocal) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(strPathLocal)
    client.DownloadFile(strFileServer, strFileLocal)
End Using

Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(strFileLocal)
    For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
        oLog.Info("Extracting " & entry.FullName & " to " & strPathLocal & "...")
        entry.ExtractToFile(strFileLocal, True)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: You can try to wait a bit until the files are unlocked using this [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/50800/1042934).

Comment: Hmm.  Well it returns immediately after the first attempt, but then gives the same error again.

Comment: Is your Anti Virus program locking the file for a small period of time. Try turning it off

Comment: You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net) how to discover which process is locking your file.

Comment: I found the issue.  It's a bug on my part.  I'm trying to ExtractToFile using the zip file's name instead of "entry.ExtractToFile(strPathLocal & entry.FullName, True)".  That explains why waiting returned immediately and handle returned nothing. :-/  Thanks for the suggestions anyway.